# Using billboards decreases performance

Tags: performance, three.js, transparency

I'm rendering billboards of objects (front, side and top planes, so 6 polygons) to replace their original mesh in large distances.

I tested a grid of 6400 trees as `BufferGeometry`, but this actually drastically drops down to 10-20 fps - using it's real geometry without transparency, 6400 with 212 faces per tree, so over 1,3 million faces compared to 38.400, it's totally fine with 60 fps.

Performance improves by not using `alphaTest` (still slower), but without, transparency doesn't work well with intersecting geometry.

So is there any way using billboards to actually improve performance?

Comment: performance is sensitive and tricky thing to optimize, you should add some code examples (jsfiddle would be nice) that reproduce the performance difference, right now we can only guess why it is so - maybe you dont merge the "billboards" and have too much drawcalls or the objects can have wierd placement and produce redundantly many fragments...

Comment: unfortunately it would take too long unwrap it into a fiddle as it's wrapped inside a engine. I'll make a fiddle of it, if it's not solved next time. The planes are made inside a single geometry, the performance issue just occurs using transparency.